# How to connect smartwatch with react native app?

Tags: react-native, iot, mobile-application, watchos, wearables

I want to create a react native app which should be connected/integrated with a smart watch to collect data points like blood pressure and heart rate from the watch and display in my mobile app. I want to ask, if there are any alternative ways to integrate watch with app? Because when I searched, everyone said buy watch which has wear OS. But these are quite expensive watches. So I wanted to ask if we can buy any kind of watch and connect with the app to get the data points?

I searched watches who are compatible with wear OS, but they are quite expensive. So, I want to know if there are any other solutions to integrate watch (which do not have wear OS) with my own mobile app.